# CSS Only method to horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have a nav bar that I'm scrolling horizontally and on hover show the child elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/vwwd6mec/

However, once the child elements are displayed i'm then able to scroll down. Anyone know how to prevent this so the on hover (child list) displays outside my div?

This is my HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li>
          <span>Dropdown 1</span>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 9</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 9</a></li>
        <li>
          <span>Dropdown 2</span>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sublink 9</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <p>Desire is to have nav bar scrollable horizontally and drop downs that aren't cut - possible without JavaScript?</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a "proof of concept", but try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ysuc9n0o/4/)

it does:

- keeps the nav items' children attached to the parent
- displays the dropdowns over the page contnet

it doesn't:

- keep the scrollbar immediately below the navbar (instead it's below the page's content)

**recap**:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">          <!-- positioned relatively so children
                                        namely .non-scrolling-container 
                                        can be attached to it -->
    <div class="fake-scroll-area"> <!-- scroll is applied to this -->
      <nav>                        <!-- scrolls with .fake-scroll-area -->
        <!-- nav contnet -->
      </nav>
      <div class="non-scrolling-content">  <!-- positioned absolutely 
                                                with respect to .container -->
        <!-- where normal page stuffgoes -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

it kind of fakes what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has to do with `position: relative` on the parent elements. If you add it to the direct parent `<li>`, then the absolute positioned child element will be nested inside all of the containers around that `<li>`. But if you only add `position: relative` to `.container` instead, then the absolute element will appear outside of the container.

See this forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tnp7hmqv/1/

The sublinks should now be appearing on top of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want. I have found this online at http://www.bootply.com/l2ChB4vYmC

The solution shows how to make a toggle side button on the nav bar.

That building such long nav bar will need javascript work I think.